# how to check what object that a method bind to?

Tags: ruby

I read about unbind method object, and have known how to bind it to particular object, Now I start wondering is there any method available to check the object a method bind to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The receiver of the method is returned by the aptly named [`Method#receiver`](http://RubyDoc.Info/stdlib/core/Method%3areceiver) method.